# why executing umlgraph command sets UMLGRAPH_HOME path to "lib"?

Tags: installation, lib, tool-uml, umlgraph

UMLGRAPH_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\lib 
The above is the path set before the execution of "umlgraph" command in command line. After my execution, the path changes to lib as UMLGRAPH_HOME=lib.
[umlgraph command check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxO12.jpg)

So, my questions are 
1) Why path is automatically set to lib and how to avoid it? 
2) If so, UmlGraph.jar needs to be kept under lib/, how to access that folder?

Answer (score 2):

I got it worked. It was because of "UMLGRAPH_HOME=lib" assignment in umlgraph.bat file in bin folder. This assignment was overwriting UMLGRAPH_HOME value. I commented it out, then it started working.